# Dynamically Create directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

i've created a directive dynamically and then i passed a data to this directive but this directive not rendered and i can access passed data into link function, and here my snippet code:

```
var table = $compile("<user-priv data=object ><user-priv>")($scope);
angular.element(document).find('#privModal').find('.modal-body').append(table);
angular.element(document).find('#privModal').modal('show')
```

And here is Directive code

```
 .directive('userPriv', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data: '=?'
        },
        templateUrl: 'file/angular/templates/privList.html',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            console.warn(scope.data);
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you succeeded or not from your post, but one thing looks off:
`restrict: 'A'` should be `restrict: 'E'` since you're using the directive as an Element, not as an Attribute.

Comment: thanks for your notice...i'v not noticed this error, sublime autocomplete is the reason. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Parameter passed to directive are always shown as html attribute: in your code you are missing some colons `""`.

Change your `$compile` line to:

```
var table = $compile("<user-priv data="object" ><user-priv>")($scope);
```